# Need to extract data from a website and store in list using regex

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing

So I have a task which requires me to extract data from a website to form a 'top 10 list'. I have chosen IMDB top 250 page http://www.imdb.com/chart/top.

In other words I need a little help using regex to isolate the names of the films and then store them in a list. I already have the HTML stored in a variable as a string (if this is the wrong way of approaching it let me know).

Also, I am limited to use of modules urlopen, re and htmlparser

```
import HTMLParser
from urllib import urlopen
import re

site = urlopen("http://www.imdb.com/chart/top?tt0468569")
content = site.read()

print content
```

Comment: Please add the code you already wrote and a specific question to your question.

Comment: Using regex to parse the data is the wrong way of approaching it. Ideally you should use BeautifulSoup, do you want an answer in regex or in BS4?

Comment: I know it's a painful way of approaching it but the requirements of the task state that we aren't allowed to use of other modules. That's kind of why I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't use regex but you stated in your comment you have to, so here it is with regex:

```
import requests

respText = requests.get("http://www.imdb.com/chart/top").text

for title in re.findall(r'<td class="titleColumn">.+?>(.+?)<', respText, re.DOTALL):
    print(title)
```

In BeautifulSoup (Which you can't use)

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(respText, "html.parser")
for item in soup.find_all("td", {"class" : "titleColumn"}):
    print(item.find("a").text)
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Funny how simple it is when you see it. Cheers mate.

Comment: No problem, just realized you can't use requests, just use your content variable instead of respText

Comment: Yea understood that. Thankyou.